# Serialize form not working and its not sending any data using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, forms

I have a bootstrap modal. Inside that modal I have a form. I would like to submit that form and my submit ajax code is outside of the modal.

The problem is when i click submit, i cant see any data being passed when using serialise.

I move the script inside the modal but again it didn't worked.

Here is My HTML form

```
<form id="update-selected-category">

                <div class="row">**strong text**
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="set">Set</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="set-input" name="set" value="<?php echo $row['down1_name']; ?>">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="description">Description</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description-input" name="description"  value="<?php echo $row['description']; ?>">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="stocklevel">Stock Level</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="stocklevel-input" name="stock-level"  value="<?php echo $row['stock_stk']; ?>">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="minlevel">Min Level</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="minlevel-input" name="min-level" value="<?php echo $row['minlevel_stk']; ?>">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="maxlevel">Max Level</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="maxlevel-input" name="max-level"  value="<?php echo $row['maxlevel_stk']; ?>">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                </form>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" id="update-category" class="btn btn-success update-category">Save</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
```

**MY JQuery**

```
            $(".update-category").click(function(){ 

                    //Create ajax request with the two paramaters
                    $.ajax({
                    url: '../data/stock.php?action=stock-category-update',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType:'text',
                    data: $( "#update-selected-category" ).serialize(), 
                    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {        
                            if(jqXHR.responseText == '{"success":"true"}'){

                                //Hide the modal
                                $('.category-update-modal').modal('hide');


                            }else{

                                //Display the bootstrap warning message
                                alert("something went wrong while saving the data");

                            }
                        },
                        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                            //Display error message to user
                            alert("An error occured when saving the data");
                        }
                    }); // End ajax request

            }); // End on click event
```

I'm not sure what i am doing wrong. The form input fields also have 'name' attributes.

**EDIT**
[alert message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbK0t.png)

Comment: is the modal dismissed or hidden on button click? or are input disabled before the serialize() call? can you provide a test link?

Comment: Modal does not get hidden on the button click. I have alert ("seccess") in Ajax request which does show up. but the data does not go through.

Comment: uhm... can you provide the entire modal structure? (some containers are missed) or a jsfiddle, please?

Answer (score 0):

Can you debug the actual error message here? Then it would easy to get the actual problem

```
error: function (err) {
    console.log("AJAX error in request: " + JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
}
```

Comment: Hello Jaed. I don't see anything in the console log.

Comment: @muhammedikram did you replace the error section what I wrote above?

Answer (score 0):

check out jquery is loaded or not. If any error in console let us know.
Check  data in alert.whether you are getting or not.

```
var a = $("form").serialize();
alert(a);
```

Comment: I tried this, empty alert message appears on screen.

Comment: Mention method post in form tag and try this.                                                                                             var form_data = new FormData($("#update-selected-category")[0]);

Comment: what would be alternative way

Comment: I tried that and alerted var form_data, alert message comes up with this  [object FormData]

Comment: checkout print_r($_POST);  in stock.php. you will get all post data if url is correct.If it is wrong check out in console.